# Trying to reverse ObjPtr to an Object I'm getting kernel not found error 53 in 64 bits but not in 32 bits

Tags: vba, pointers, com

I'm referring Parent class from Child class; instead of simply do, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38211009/vba-pass-parent-class-to-child-class):

```
Public Property Set Parent(obj As ClassProperties)
    Set this.ParentColl = obj
End Property
```

I rather prefer to avoid references to and from getting entangled and 'out of memory' error when I loop through and create instances of the class so I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478136/vba-object-destruction-memory-error) that is based on [that](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2007/12/28/terminating-dependent-classes/#comment-29661).

It functions as a charm in 32 bits but at 64 bits I'm getting **Runtime error '53' File not found: kernel.**

In a module:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
     (dest As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
#Else
    Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
     (dest As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
#End If

'Returns an object given its pointer.
Public Function ObjFromPtr(ByVal pObj As Long) As Object
    Dim obj As Object
    CopyMemory obj, pObj, 4
    Set ObjFromPtr = obj
    CopyMemory obj, 0&, 4
End Function

Public Function ObjFromPtrVBA7(ByVal pObj As LongPtr) As Object
    Dim obj As Object
    CopyMemory obj, pObj, 4  <== here is the error
    Set ObjFromPtrVBA7 = obj
    CopyMemory obj, 0&, 4
End Function
```

At Child class:

```
    #If VBA7 Then 'Uses modParentChildDereference
    Private mlParentPtr As LongPtr
    #Else
    Private mlParentPtr As Long
    #End If
Public Property Get Parent() As ClassProperties 
    #If VBA7 Then 'Uses modParentChildDereference
    Set Parent = modParentChildDereference.ObjFromPtrVBA7(mlParentPtr)
    #Else
    Set Parent = modParentChildDereference.ObjFromPtr(mlParentPtr)
    #End If
End Property
Public Property Set Parent(obj As ClassProperties)
    mlParentPtr = ObjPtr(obj)
End Property
```

At Parent Class:

```
    Set newItem.Parent = Me
```

At CopyMemory obj, **pObj**, 4 I can see the LongPtr, like 1234567789^, but CopyMemory is unable to find the Obj at kernel.

I read some deep threads over CopyMemory [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?572690-CopyMemory-Function) and [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?786079-VB6-Modern-Shell-Interface-Type-Library-oleexp-tlb/page2).

Based on those I played a little with CopyMemory obj, pObj, **4** and gave it different numbers, like 8 and 16 but to no avail.

Any directions or solutions?
TIA

Comment: Take a look at this implementation, it should work well: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/202414/solution-for-parent-child-circular-references-weakreference-class

Comment: @UnhandledException; their implementation is very good and also ONLY WORKS IN 32 BITS, although it seems to work in 64... but I got different errors with his - including crash windows - but I paid attention to one comment there and could figure out the solution, answered below. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link provided by @UnhandledException in the comment above directed me to an [amazing thread](http://Solution%20for%20Parent/Child%20circular%20references:%20WeakReference%20class)

I implemented it, adapting to 64 bits - [see my answer there](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/239725/186595) - and got a totally different kind of errors, even crashing VBE, video driver and windows.

But one comment at OP opened my eyes:

> Please don't hard-code the size... ever. LenB is to VBA what sizeof is
>   to C. Use it to size the allocation for the copy memory API. – this

Back to work:

```
Public Function ObjFromPtr(ByVal pObj As Long) As Object
    Dim obj As Object
    CopyMemory obj, pObj, LenB(obj) 'not size 4!
    Set ObjFromPtr = obj
    CopyMemory obj, 0&, LenB(obj) 'not size 4!
End Function

Public Function ObjFromPtrVBA7(ByVal pObj As LongPtr) As Object
    Dim obj As Object
    CopyMemory obj, pObj, LenB(obj) 'not size 4!  <== here the error no more!!!!
    Set ObjFromPtrVBA7 = obj
    CopyMemory obj, 0&, LenB(obj) 'not size 4!
End Function
```

So, answered.

Thanks a  lot community!

Comment: How can `LenB(obj)` return a value if `obj` is `Nothing`?

Comment: @AdamL.S., see `CopyMemory Lib "kernel32"` definition: pObj is source, obj is dest; so, LenB(obj) will be calculated after obj is assigned...

Comment: @Marcelo, thats not right. LenB(obj) will be calculated first because its required as parameter to call CopyMemory. But at that time, obj is Null (other than pObj, which is just an integer of the right size).

Comment: Thinking about it, I realized the size of `obj` and `pObj` have same size (otherwise you couldn't copy from one to another), so it should be `LenB(pObj)` otherwise this would stop executing at `CopyMemory` call.

Answer (score 0):

Even on a 64-bit Windows and 64-bit Office (VBA), the kernel dll is still "kernel32"!
Thats what "Runtime error '53' File not found: kernel." clearly sayd.

In fact, all 64bit system libraries are located under `%SystemRoot%\System32` whereas the same libraries for 32bit subsystems are in `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64`.
(Yes, thats right, even when the naming suggest the reverse)

So

```
#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
     (dest As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
#End If
```

works for both, Office32 and Office64 systems as long as they already use the VBA7 engine.

But Marcelo is also right, `LenB(pObj)` (pObj or any LongPtr variable) should be used as length parameter. But LenB(obj), as suggested by Marcelo, doesnt work for me (Office2013) because obj is Nothing and LenB tries to derefer the obj instance.

Comment: Strange... after you do `CopyMemory obj, pObj, LenB(obj)`, pObj will be copied to obj and this will turn `obj` in a not nulll object. Are you sure `pObj` is actually not null?

Comment: `LenB(pObj)` will not work because `CopyMemory` _has_ to copy pObj (source object) to another place of memory as a destination obj; to do that it has to copy a specific number of bits, i e, the obj's length; this is what do the magic of get a C object of different DWORD length and translate to a VBA object...

Comment: It will work because you want copy the pointer, not the object itself. `LenB(pObj)` is supposed to give you the size of the pointer variable, either 4 or 8 depending on 32 or 64 bit.